# CHARMM36 Parameters for Neutral Arginine

Tags: gromacs, charmm

I am looking for CHARMM36 parameters for Neutral Arginine. Protonated form of Argnine is already available in CHARMM36 library, but not the same for Neutral. Thanks.

With best regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick search of the toppar folder in CHARMM shows that there are three patches that are available to create neutral arginine from the charged arginine.

This is the sample input

```
* Reads the DCA residue from the stream topology file and writes a pdb consisting
* of a single DCA molecule
*

bomlev -5
wrnlev -5

!topology and parameter files
open read card unit 10 name ./toppar/top_all36_prot.rtf
read  rtf card unit 10 

open read card unit 20 name ./toppar/par_all36m_prot.prm
read para card unit 20 flex

stream ./toppar/toppar_all36_prot_arg0.str

read sequence ARG 1
generate ARG first nter last cter

ic generate
ic param
ic seed 1 N 1 CA 1 C 
ic build
print ic

coor build
coor print
hbuild sele all end

mini sd 10000 1000

open write card unit 30 name arginine_charged.pdb
write coor pdb  unit 30
close unit 30

patch RN1 ARG 1
autogen angle dihe 
ic build
coor build

open write card unit 30 name arginine_neutral.pdb
write coor pdb  unit 30

close unit 30
```